# NoMethodError (undefined method `empty?' for #<Event:0x6042e88>):

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, activemodel

I created a rails API using **postgre** database in which i have a model (table) name as **counseling_event**

**NOTE:** Not using **scaffold** and using **rails-5**

My scheman(migration)  for **counseling_event** is as follow:

```
class CreateCounselingEvent < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
def change
create_table :counseling_event do |t|
  t.text :name
  t.datetime :start_time
  t.datetime :end_time
  t.text :location
  t.integer :user_id
  t.integer :role_id
  t.timestamps
 end
 end
end
```

I added a column to the above table, which is of type enum. column name is event_type

Now, In my Controller i.e CounselingEventController, in my action index i'm retrieving the data from the counseling_event table. the code is as follows.

```
def index
  @counseling_event = CounselingEvent.where(start_time: "2016-10-30".."2016-12-11")
  render body: @counseling_event
end
```

when i call this api controller action from frontend through following route

```
get 'counseling_event/index'
```

I'm getting this error in my console:

```
CounselingEvent Load (1.5ms)  SELECT "counseling_event".* FROM "counseling_event"

    NoMethodError (undefined method `empty?' for #<CounselingEvent:0x47d1d58>):

    activemodel (5.0.0.1) lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:433:in `method_missing'
    rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/etag.rb:68:in `block in digest_body'
    activerecord (5.0.0.1) lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:38:in `each'
    activerecord (5.0.0.1) lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:38:in `each'
    actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/http/response.rb:145:in `each_chunk'
    actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/http/response.rb:126:in `each'
    actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/http/response.rb:74:in `each'
    actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/http/response.rb:464:in `each'
    rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/etag.rb:66:in `digest_body'
    rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/etag.rb:29:in `call'
    rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/conditional_get.rb:38:in `call'
    rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/head.rb:12:in `call'
    activerecord (5.0.0.1) lib/active_record/migration.rb:552:in `call'
    actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:38:in `block in call'
    activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:97:in `__run_callbacks__'
    activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:750:in `_run_call_callbacks'
    activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:90:in `run_callbacks'
    actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:36:in `call'
    actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in `call'
    actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:79:in `call'
    actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:49:in `call'
    actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:31:in `call'
    railties (5.0.0.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:36:in `call_app'
    railties (5.0.0.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `block in call'
    activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:70:in `block in tagged'
    activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
    activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:70:in `tagged'
    railties (5.0.0.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `call'
    actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:24:in `call'
    rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
    activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
    actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in `call'
    actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:136:in `call'
    rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:111:in `call'
    rack-cors (0.4.0) lib/rack/cors.rb:80:in `call'
    railties (5.0.0.1) lib/rails/engine.rb:522:in `call'
    puma (3.6.0) lib/puma/configuration.rb:225:in `call'
    puma (3.6.0) lib/puma/server.rb:578:in `handle_request'
    puma (3.6.0) lib/puma/server.rb:415:in `process_client'
    puma (3.6.0) lib/puma/server.rb:275:in `block in run'
    puma (3.6.0) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:116:in `call'
    puma (3.6.0) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:116:in `block in spawn_thread'
```

I don't know the reason for the error but, trying hard to resolve it. can any one help me out to solve this error. it seems like some activemodel error. Thanks in advance.

Comment: even am facing the same issue,i tried with different devices and environment but it didnt help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rails is based on Rack. Rack can only handle strings. You're rendering an object, not a string.

You probably want something like:

```
render plain: @counceling_event.to_s
```

It basically happens because Rack attempts to call `#empty?` on the body of the response to determine how it should respond to the client.

But since your `@counceling_event` isn't a string and doesn't respond to `empty?` it fails.

I'm unsure what you're trying to do by `render body: <SOMETHING>`. If you're on a Rails app you probably want to render a view instead of content directly from the controller.

If you really want to render from the controller you should consider using `render plain: <SOMETHING>`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: You may be correct @Emil the problem got resolved after replacing `render body` . I was using `render body` to fetch exactly the active records from my database. I would encourage any further explanation.Thank You.