# How to fix "undefined method `empty?' for ...:Float"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to create a very simple "compute" method, but when loading the page with params "?op1=20&op2=30&operation=plus", I get this error:

NoMethodError in CalcController#compute

undefined method `empty?' for 50.0:Float.

My method:

```
def compute
        operation = params['operation']
        op1=params['op1']
        op2=params['op2']
        if operation==nil or op1==nil or op2==nil
            render plain: 'Error:invalid params...'
            return
        end
        if operation=='plus'
            render plain: op1.to_f+op2.to_f
            return
        end
end
```

The extracted source:

```
body.each do |part|
    parts << part
    (digest ||= Digest::SHA256.new) << part unless part.empty?
end

[digest && digest.hexdigest.byteslice(0, 32), parts]
```

The complete error stack:

```
rack (2.0.7) lib/rack/etag.rb:68:in `block in digest_body'
actionpack (5.1.7) lib/action_dispatch/http/response.rb:145:in `each'
actionpack (5.1.7) lib/action_dispatch/http/response.rb:145:in `each_chunk'
actionpack (5.1.7) lib/action_dispatch/http/response.rb:126:in `each'
actionpack (5.1.7) lib/action_dispatch/http/response.rb:74:in `each'
actionpack (5.1.7) lib/action_dispatch/http/response.rb:473:in `each'
rack (2.0.7) lib/rack/etag.rb:66:in `digest_body'
rack (2.0.7) lib/rack/etag.rb:29:in `call'
rack (2.0.7) lib/rack/conditional_get.rb:25:in `call'
rack (2.0.7) lib/rack/head.rb:12:in `call'
activerecord (5.1.7) lib/active_record/migration.rb:556:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:26:in `block in call'
activesupport (5.1.7) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:97:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (5.1.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:24:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:59:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:31:in `call'
railties (5.1.7) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:36:in `call_app'
railties (5.1.7) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `block in call'
activesupport (5.1.7) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:69:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (5.1.7) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
activesupport (5.1.7) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:69:in `tagged'
railties (5.1.7) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:79:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:25:in `call'
rack (2.0.7) lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
activesupport (5.1.7) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:125:in `call'
rack (2.0.7) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:111:in `call'
railties (5.1.7) lib/rails/engine.rb:522:in `call'
puma (3.12.1) lib/puma/configuration.rb:227:in `call'
puma (3.12.1) lib/puma/server.rb:660:in `handle_request'
puma (3.12.1) lib/puma/server.rb:474:in `process_client'
puma (3.12.1) lib/puma/server.rb:334:in `block in run'
puma (3.12.1) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:135:in `block in spawn_thread'
```

Comment: Is `50.0` in the URL, if so the dot might need escaping.

Comment: Also try `render plain: (op1.to_f + op2.to_f).to_s`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error occurs because you're trying to check if a Float object is `empty?`. `empty?` is a method defined for objects of the enumerable type(Arrays, hashes etc.). To check if an object contains some value or not, you could use `.blank?`.
In your code, `(digest ||= Digest::SHA256.new) << part unless part.empty?` this line, could be changed to `(digest ||= Digest::SHA256.new) << part unless part.blank?`

Rails provides a few very similar methods, which are briefly described below:

`empty?`: Is a method defined for enumerable objects (Arrays, hashes etc.)
`blank?`: This is defined for objects which are initialized with an empty value or are null. So `"".blank?` will return `true`, as well as `nil.blank?`
`.nil?`: This is a method to specifically check if the value of a variable is `nil`. `"".nil?` will return `false`, but `nil.nil?` will return true.

For more details, you could check out [this blog](https://blog.arkency.com/2017/07/nil-empty-blank-ruby-rails-difference/)
UPDATE:

As mentioned in the update in the question, this error seems to occur at a Rack level, and not in the main source code. The reason for that is that the Rack middleware expects to handle strings, and not other types of objects. 
In the `compute` action, we render a float object in the line `render plain: op1.to_f+op2.to_f`. This causes Rack to raise an error since it expects to receive only strings for rendering. This could be resolved by typecasting the matter to be rendered to a string as follows:
`render plain: (op1.to_f+op2.to_f).to_s`
Kudos to @Emil Kampp for [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40883029/5362761) that helped in debugging.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't clarify that that "extracted source" is not inside my code.

Comment: Where exactly does it reside and how is it getting invoked? 
Is it a part of some gem that you're using?

Comment: I'm not really sure... I added the error stack if it can help.

Comment: It seems to occur because the `lib/rack/etag.rb` file receives the float directly instead of a string, that it expects.

Comment: Actually, I just read this answer which seems to have cleared up the issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40883029/5362761
Basically, when we render, we need to render a string, not an object. Changing `render plain: op1.to_f+op2.to_f` to `render plain: (op1.to_f+op2.to_f).to_s` should solve it.
I'll update the answer as well if that works.

Comment: Perfectly working now, thanks for the help!